# Removing version number from file name with Maven

Tags: java, build, maven-2, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I have a project with 5 modules in maven. Right now, when I do a "mvn clean install", it generates an ear containing the two jars, one war and one sar from the other modules.

All the file names contain the version, e.g., projectx-ear-2.0.0.ear, projectx-client-2.0.0.jar, etc.

I need to rename one of the jars and the final ear to omit the version in the file name. It should look like this:

```
projectx-ear.ear
|
+-- projectx-client.jar
|
+-- projectx-misc-2.0.0.jar
|
+-- projectx-sar-2.0.0.sar
|
\-- projectx-web-2.0.0.web
```

Right now I'm using the following plugins to build:
maven-compiler-plugin and maven-release-plugin

What would be the best way to achieve the results I expect?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your ear module, you can either use the `project.build.finalName` element or you can configure the [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) which supports a [`finalName`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#finalName) optional parameter. And to configure the final name of a bundled jar, you'll need to define a [`jarModule`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html#jarModule) and to set the `bundleFileName` property for it.

The final configuration might looks something like that (I'll demonstrate how to set the  the final ear name in the plugin configuration here):

```
<project>
  [...]
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>yourgroupid</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectx-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version><!-- not mandatory if inherited -->
    </dependency>
    [...]
  </dependencies>
  [...]  
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>projectx-ear</finalName>
          <modules>
            <jarModule>
              <groupId>yourgroupid</groupId>
              <artifactId>projectx-client</artifactId>
              <bundleFileName>anotherName.jar</bundleFileName>
            </jarModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

Comment: As of now, later versions of the plugin (I am using 2.6) allows you to specify inside `<configuration>` a `<fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>` that deletes the version number of your modules (so you do not have to define each of them). The ear name is not affected by this, though.

Answer (score 118):

You can achieve this by specifying the `finalName` property in your pom like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Point one : single JAR/WAR.**

To create it without version number in name, in pom.xml simply add the code:

```
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

So, if you compile, for example projectx_misc, you get *projectx_misc.jar* .

What happens to me? When I compile the same package from a POM project (in Netbeans), all the jars have the version in the name and the EAR include the xxx-version.jar archives.

**So, point two: the EAR problem.**

In the EAR's pom.xml file, change the *maven-ear-plugin* adding in the configuration this property:

```
<fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
```

This is my plugin setting for example:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8</version>
   <configuration>
       <version>6</version>
       <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
       <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So, now when i compile all the archives from a project pom, all the version numbers are removed from the jars.