# Maven artifact version number in jar file

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven 3 for build xxx-common module

After building my application i get my jar file as xxx-common-0.0.1.jar

this is getting deployed into my artifactory as

http://localhost:8800/artifactory/core-release/com/xxx/xxx-common/0.0.1/xxx-common-0.0.1.jar

That deployment is good,

Here, how can I eliminate version number getting appended " **xxx-common-0.0.1.jar** " and need it just as " **xxx-common.jar** "

Kindly help out to overcome this problem guys...

---

Sorry it didn't worked out

Below is what i gave....

```
<plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 

        </plugins>
```

executed using

mvn package

and

Installing /home/xxx/build-deploy-tools/.jenkins/jobs/workspace/xxx-common/target/xxx-common.jar to /home/xxx/.m2/repository/com/xxx/xxx-common/0.0.1/xxx-common-0.0.1.jar

Still it pushes as xxx-common-0.0.1.jar

Comment: This is the maven convention.  Why would you want it to be different?

Comment: This is very similar to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225142/removing-version-number-from-file-name-with-maven. (It actually answers the question as well...)

Answer (score 6):

In your repository, you cannot ever get rid of the numbers. In your target directory, you can use a `finalName` element in the configuration of the [Maven JAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can define it at the `outputFileNameMapping` config option for you project.

This option defaults to

```
${module.artifactId}-${module.version}${dashClassifier?}.${module.extension}
```

So, in your case, you could change it to

```
${module.artifactId}.${module.extension}
```

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

Comment: No reason to believe that the OP is using the assembly plugin at all.